# What font comes close to this?

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm hooked on this typography. Any idea if there's a font which comes close to this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling for  "neon sign fonts".?

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes but nothing comes close

Comment: perhaps look at the handwriting fonts over on dafont(dot)com - there are hundreds of them.

Comment: Have you done some research? There are tons of sites with handwriting fonts. Perhaps it's not free. Is this an actual photo or a 3D rendering? Where does it come from?

Comment: It looks like a font with an action or text effect on it.
I isolated the text here if anyone has better luck than me. https://imgur.com/a/JGlCp

Comment: If this is just done in Photoshop, it took a lot of work. I feel like I can see the three-dimensional loops in the glass tube and note how the 'e's are different. It's either custom lettering or if it's a font it's been very, very heavily modified. I don't think you're going to be able to get a font that matches this complexity–this looks like custom lettering to me.